# Need help to get a sub string from a given string

Tags: c#, string, split

I have the  below string in application

string s = .\abc_xyz\drff\dsqa_license_db\dgfx\xsad_license_db.rfds-17343;

and i need sub string from the above string as .\abc_xyz\drff\

Please help me do achieve this

thanks

Comment: what is the criteria and what have you tried by yourself?

Comment: This has been answered many times before, and the answer is easily found by a simple web search. Tip: `String.Substring(0, 14)` [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: As Selman22 said, how do you know that's the string you want? The first 15 characters? Everything from the start to the third '\' character? What are the criteria?

Comment: creteria is i want to split the string on 3rd slash from the first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string s = @".\abc_xyz\drff\dsqa_license_db\dgfx\xsad_license_db.rfds-17343";

  string[] splitChar = { @"\"};

 int yourCriteria = 3;

   string[]  splitString = s.Split(splitChar, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

 for (int i = 0; i < yourCriteria; i++)
  {
     if (sb.Length == 0)
   sb.AppendFormat("{0}", splitString[i]);
   else
  sb.AppendFormat(@"\{0}", splitString[i]);

  }
    //now do whatever you want to with sb.ToString();
```